# Does running a command in shell using crons consume more server resources than executing a laravel command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh, cron

I am executing the `queue:work` command using a cron every 15 minutes on a shared server currently. Today, when I saw the number of processes running, it was 23 processes. I am afraid I would get an email from my host soon or the server would crash or maybe it won't function properly.

And another server where I have just 1 command running daily morning, the number of processes running was 0.

I wonder whether the direct execution of a command from the cron is taking up more resources and does executing a laravel command using a cron take up less resources ?

It seems to me that every 15 minutes, a new instance of a shell is run and the  `queue:work` command is executed. I am also notified of `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error multiple times a day due to this.

Kindly guide on a proper approach to this. I cannot afford a VPS/Dedicated server as of now. My shared server allows running a cron with a minimum interval of 15 minutes.

Comment: _"I cannot afford a VPS"_ - You can get a VPS for $5. Regarding your question, if you have 23 processes running, it seems like the process doesn't close properly, or are you executing the same command while the previous process is still running? Also, the error _"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"_ is easily solved by simply checking if the variable/property is an array before trying to iterate through it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson before tax, for me its 6$ cheapest on DO. OP you need to enlighten us what you are executing... share codes etc.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Well, I am already going through the reviews of Digital Ocean / Scaleway, etc. But I haven't yet reached a conclusion on which server to use. Your guidance would be highly appreciated.

`it seems like the process doesn't close properly, or are you executing the same command while the previous process is still running?` Yes, because when I execute this command on local server, the process doesn't end as the command is used to process a queue. I do not know when it ends, even if it does for that sake.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Moreover, the error is solvable, as you said. But I am also concerned about the resources of my server. I am looking for an optimal solution.

Comment: @Kyslik - I also told you I was executing the `php artisan queue:work' command. As this is more of a theoretical question, it won't require much codes, I suppose.

Comment: Shared server costs me $1 incl. taxes and my requirement suffices as of now. So carrying on with it. I would definitely require a VPS soon though.

Comment: Vivek obviously you have some problems with jobs because of `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error. The thing is that `queue:work` is designed to work as daemon and supervisord (or any other process manager, systemd) is supposed to be looking after this daemon, if its dead it will run it again. You spawn new daemon every 15 minutes and some of them die because of the foreach error.

Comment: I am running this queue for sending emails whenever a new note is published. The emails would be sent to around hundreds of people. So, I want to run the command all the time and especially, just one instance of it. I also researched and learnt about the `run-one` command, but it supposedly runs on ubuntu only and not on my server. I know supervisord is the best way to handle this, but shared server won't allow it.

Comment: You seem to not get what I am telling you, `queue:work` spawns new PHP process with current application code and it crunches all the jobs in the queue and if its done, it waits until new job comes in or until it errors out (foreach error) or you stop it via command. You want to have only one `queue:work` running unless you have multiple queues.

Comment: @Kyslik - You mean I should just initiate it just once, and it would keep running. If so, I already tried that. But somehow the emails are not sent and my jobs table is filled with pending jobs.

Comment: Well because the foreach error stops the worker and is not revived by supervisord/systemd... you revive it every 15 minutes but if for some reason foreach error does not happen you have `1+n` workers now.

Comment: No, I tried to do this before I setup the cron. If somehow, I come to know how to stop the instance of the `queue:work` command, my problem would be solved. On the local server, when I initiate the command, it would process all the pending emails and then nothing happens, it doesn't end like other commands. It seems to be waiting for other jobs dispatched to the queue.

Comment: Should I try running the cron once a day at 00:01 ? At least the errors would reduce and less resources consumed. I could give it a try.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thats how it works, you want to have only one `queue:work` running. Since worker encounters error with foreach it gets killed! And your emails are no longer being sent. You spawn new worker every 15 minutes even if one is already running. Fix the foreach error first! Then come back here we can talk more on how to set the cron or we can come up with different solution.

Comment: The comments helped me too thanks guys great support :)